# Message History and Jolokia MBeans

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there any way to get history from a queue?
I'm able to get the current count of messages that are in the queue, but is it possible to get a number of all messages that already passed on this queue?

Comment: Please only ask a single question per "question."  If you have more than one question please hit the "Ask Question" button for each.

Comment: Edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following metrics:

- `MessagesAdded` - number of messages added to this queue since it was created
- `MessagesAcknowledged` - number of messages acknowledged from this queue since it was created
- `MessagesExpired` - number of messages expired from this queue since it was created
- `MessagesKilled` - number of messages removed from this queue since it was created due to exceeding the max delivery attempts

Comment: But can I use this by jolokia?
I'm currently using this URL to get Queue info: http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%220.0.0.0%22,address=%22ADDRESS.NAME%22,component=addresses

Comment: And I mount this URL based on the info that I get here: /console/jolokia/list

Comment: Justin, now I understand. Thanks. I'm able to find these information using the URL: http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:address="ADDRESS.NAME",broker="BROKER.NAME",component=addresses,queue="QUEUE.NAME",routing-type="anycast",subcomponent=queues. Need to use subcomponent Queues. 
Could you provide the link where the information that you provide are avaliable? Thanks